# Is it a good idea to skip upvoted answers in the Low Quality Answers queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts, low-quality-answers

I noticed that upvoted and/or accepted answers cannot be deleted via review in Low Quality Answers. A moderator ends up deleting the post anyway, invalidating the task.

Here is an example:

[image: Example]

If such upvoted, low quality answers have to be deleted by moderators anyway, is there any reason to **not** <kbd>Skip</kbd> the task outright if I see an answer that I would <kbd>Recommend deletion</kbd> but is upvoted and/or accepted?

Comment: perfect example of how confusing meta is - I find this a very good question that was very much worth asking, but the answer is "hell no". I need two vote buttons.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No you should not. Even though upvoted answers cannot be deleted with the LQA queue it raises an automatic mod flag if it gets enough <kbd>Recommend deletion</kbd> reviews. According to this answer on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292/1117855) 4 <kbd>Recommend deletion</kbd> reviews here on SO will get an automatic mod flag raised. You can also downvote it to get it to a score of 0 or -1 but only do so if you think it should be downvoted.